# Multi country Amazon affiliate links

Tags: internationalization, affiliate, amazon

I know how to create Amazon affiliate product links in my YouTube video descriptions.

The problem is that (AFAIK) the affiliate links are to the Amazon.com site.

Many of my viewers are coming from countries with their own Amazon site and amazon.com does not ship there. For example https://www.amazon.co.uk/.

Beside listing many link to the product to many Amazon country sites, is there any better/smarter way to get multi country link such that I don't have to list a link to so many country link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the U.K. and Canada, there's Onelink:

http://amazonassociates.typepad.com/us/2017/07/monetize-your-uk-and-canada-traffic-with-onelink.html

I expect that more countries eventually will be added.

The bad part is that payment is made by check in the currency of each country, and most banks charge hefty fees for cashing or depositing foreign checks. Setting a high payment threshold helps.

Comment: This is brilliant. Do you know it also redirects the US customers to amazon.com?

Comment: I did not. But now I do!

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, you mentioned "I did not. But now I do!" -> does that means the approach you explained works for US customers as well (means works for CA,UK and US?

Comment: I knew it worked for U.S. affiliates selling in CA and UK. I didn't know it worked for affiliates in CA and UK selling to customers in US. I'm old. I only learn what I need to know these days.

Comment: Being old is a good thing, means you have experienced and know where to put your focus on.